# TSQL joining two tables to get desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem getting the desired result for this. For example I have tables like this

**Table1**

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|SerialId |serialidtagging |unifiedserial |     CreatedDatetime     | Wrkctrid | Embedded|  
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|89250432 |   89250432-1   |    3266AD    | 2016-11-19 18:51:06.000 | Entry    |DRC53030 |
|89250432 |   89250432-2   |    3266AD    | 2017-01-05 17:30:45.000 | Entry    |F1461350 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Table2**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|unifiedserial |Pool| PoNum  |       audit_date        |Row_Num |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|    3266AD    | IP |07664594| 2016-11-22 18:42:07.000 |   1    |
|    3266AD    | PL |07733189| 2016-11-26 02:24:12.000 |   2    |
|    3266AD    | PL |07771562| 2016-11-29 02:01:28.000 |   3    |
|    3266AD    | Re |07784874| 2016-11-29 14:42:05.000 |   4    |
|    3266AD    | IP |08394765| 2017-01-09 09:56:59.000 |   5    |
|    3266AD    | Re |08427441| 2017-01-10 19:04:37.000 |   6    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|unifiedserial |Pool|  PoNum   |      audit_date        |Row_num| serialidtagging |serialid |    createddatetime      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   3266AD     |IP  | 07664594 |2016-11-22 18:42:07.000 |   1   |   89250432-1    |89250432 | 2016-11-19 18:51:06.000 |
|   3266AD     |PL  | 07733189 |2016-11-26 02:24:12.000 |   2   |   89250432-1    |89250432 | 2016-11-19 18:51:06.000 |
|   3266AD     |PL  | 07771562 |2016-11-29 02:01:28.000 |   3   |   89250432-1    |89250432 | 2016-11-19 18:51:06.000 |
|   3266AD     |Re  | 07784874 |2016-11-29 14:42:05.000 |   4   |   89250432-1    |89250432 | 2016-11-19 18:51:06.000 |
|   3266AD     |IP  | 08394765 |2017-01-09 09:56:59.000 |   5   |   89250432-2    |89250432 | 2017-01-05 17:30:45.000 |
|   3266AD     |Re  | 08427441 |2017-01-10 19:04:37.000 |   6   |   89250432-2    |89250432 | 2017-01-05 17:30:45.000 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When joining the tables, my reference is the **unifiedserial**
Is is possible to get my Desired Output. If only **unifiedserial** is the reference? As you can see in table1 `createddatetime = 2016-11-19 18:51:06.000` I don't know if it is possible to get the **table2** `audit_date` only from the month of `audit_date = createddatetime`. As far as I know is that I can get this through `><= Month of createddatetime-audit_date`

Sorry if it is lack of explanation. But please rely on the Sample table and output.

TIA!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.unifiedserial = t2.unifiedserial
AND DATEPART(month,t1.createddatetime) = DATEPART(month,t2.audit_date)
AND DATEPART(year,t1.createddatetime) = DATEPART(year,t2.audit_date)
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I get the desired output, but before I accept the answer let me check first if it is effective in my large volume of table.

Comment: Define effective for us?

Comment: Effective for me. Meets my desired output :)